# Drush PHP syntax error when running

Tags: drush

I am following the instructions to install Drush that are listed on this page: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/install.md

I seem to be getting a syntax error within the code:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.0.0-rc4/drush.phar
--2015-11-16 16:23:02--  https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.0.0-rc4/drush.phar
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.131
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.131|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
2015-11-16 16:23:05 (1.47 MB/s) - drush.phar saved [3496991/3496991]

[user@localhost ~]$ php drush.phar core-status

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar:///home/user/drush.phar/includes/output.inc on line 188
```

I am not seeing this error on Google. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Are you running drush inside the Drupal directory?

Comment: `PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Nov  3 2015 15:43:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`

Comment: It happens when I run in a Drupal directory and when I do not. Regardless, I don't think this is how Drush normally reacts to not finding an installation. Other versions have gracefully exited.

Comment: I will add to make sure you check if you have the `DRUSH_PHP` environment variable set. I spent way too long trying to figure out why drush wasn't using php 5.6 even though that was what was configured in my path.  Turns out I had `DRUSH_PHP` set to my php 5.3 path from a long time ago. `unset DRUSH_PHP` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using Drush 8, which requires a minimum PHP version of 5.4.5 (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/).

Your current version (5.3) doesn't understand short array syntax, hence the error you're seeing.

To fix, either upgrade PHP, or switch to an older branch of Drush.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have PHP 5.3.29, Drupal 6 (installed php using phpbrew on Ubuntu 14.04 and then switched to version 5.3.29). When I run command `drush status` I am getting:

Warning: Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 63

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 63

Answer (score 0):

If your system has more than one php versions installed you can define an alias in your *.bashrc* or *.bash_profile* or */etc/profile.d/global_aliases.sh* (or any part of your system that you can define an alias). The alias would run drush with appropriate php version.

For example in a plesk system you can probably do something like this

```
alias drush='/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php /usr/local/drush'
```